# Laravel API Route - 404

Tags: laravel, url-routing, laravel-routing, laravel-api

I'm building an API to support an external application. I have added several routes to it with no problem, but suddenly, when I add a new route (`acars/delay`), I get a 404 error when trying to hit `http://myurl.dev/api/acars/delay` with a POST request. Here is my `api.php` file:

```
Route::post('acars/deactivate', 'API\AcarsController@deactivate');

Route::post('acars/ofp', 'API\AcarsController@ofp');

Route::post('acars/create', 'API\AcarsController@create');

Route::post('acars/pirep', 'API\AcarsController@pirep');

Route::post('acars/mx', 'API\AcarsController@mx');

Route::post('acars/delay', 'API\AcarsController@delay'); // <-- THIS IS THE BROKEN ROUTE
```

Controller method:

```
public function delay(Request $request) {
    $acars = AcarsFlight::findOrFail($request->acars_flight_id);
    $delay = AcarsDelay::create([
        ...
    ]);
    return $delay;
}
```

The other routes work fine, but `acars/delay` returns a 404 in Postman every time. My `php artisan route:list` output looks like this:

[image: Output of php artisan route:list]

There are no wildcards causing conflicts. I have tried clearing my route cache multiple times, restarting the server, etc. I have also tried moving the broken route to different positions in the `api.php` file, but no luck. The only thing I can think of is that I recently upgraded the application from Laravel 6 to 8. I read the upgrade guides for v7 and v8, and the only thing I found was that in starting v7, [unique route names are required](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#unique-route-names), a requirement I believe I have met. I have verified about a thousand times that I'm using the right URL. Copying+pasting the URL into the browser gives me the extected `405` error.

Comment: can you show that controller method

Comment: It might be because of something like `findOrFail` method in your controller. Try to `dd` at start of your controller and try requesting with Postman again

Comment: @lagbox Added in

Comment: @Parsa_Gholipour Interesting, just added in my controller which does include a `findOrFail`

Comment: @Parsa_Gholipour Spot on with that! Can't believe I missed that! If you answer, I'll accept. Thanks for the tip! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because of something like `findOrFail` method in your controller. Try to `dd` at start of your controller and try requesting with Postman again.

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't even think to look at the controller

Comment: @AndrewDeForest You are welcome ;), That actually happened to me before, that's why I guessed